# Screencast from own glassware

Tags: android, google-glass

Is there a way to provide a video feed of what the glass is currently displaying ?
I am looking for a way to do something similar to the screencast from the MyGlass app, but directing the feed to wherever I need it (probably to my server)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your Glass with `adb` and then mirror the Android device screen to your PC.

A tutorial can be found [here](http://neatocode.tumblr.com/post/49566072064/mirroring-google-glass).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer and the link! I did not know about that and it seems pretty cool.
I was however trying to get the video feed programatically, and then maybe send it to my backend using a web service or something along those lines... Thanks anyways!